# MobileFirst and Worklight with Java 8

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, hybrid-mobile-app

How to use Java 8 for MobileFirst / Worklight mobile applications? I have always encountered articles that it wouldn't work with Java 8. Any one had luck in using it with Java 8?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At this time, MobileFirst does not support Java8. We're actively working on this and we should be able to announce support "soon".  Be aware that there are several different aspects to your issue -

- Developer environment; CLI and Studio, and embedded Liberty server
- MobileFirst Server, of many different flavors; Liberty, WAS, Tomcat, etc.

Suggest you ask your question again in a week or so, and I should be able to provide a more specific answer.